# Food accidentally cooked on Yom Kippur

Tags: halacha, yom-kippur, eating, intent-accident-purposely

If one [b'shogeig](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1225/170) cooked food on Yom Kippur, would he able to eat that food after Yom Kippur, assuming he waited after Yom Kippur the time it took to cook it?  I know that the rule of food cooked on Yom Kippur is different than the rule of food cooked on Shabbos.  (See Rav Yitzchok Zilberstein)

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR should DEF [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)

(having said that, in the interest of learning would like to take a stab at it)

---

The **Shulchan Aruch**, [Orach Chaim 611:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.611.2?lang=bi&p2=Mishneh_Torah%2C_Rest_on_the_Tenth_of_Tishrei.1.2&lang2=bi) establishes the principle that Yom Kippur is like Shabbos:

> כל מלאכה שחייבים עליה בשבת חייבים עליה ביום הכפורים וכל שבשבת פטור אבל אסור גם ביום הכפורים כן
>
> Any laborous activity for which one is liable on Shabbat, one is liable on Yom Kippur; anything which is forbidden on Shabbat without liability is also forbidden on Yom Kippur

Following this principle that Yom Kippur = Shabbos, let's see what the **Shulchan Aruch** ([Orach Chaim 318:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.318.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) says about one who cooks food accidentally on Shabbos:

> המבשל בשבת  <sub>[או שעשה א' משאר מלאכות] [טור]</sub> במזיד אסור לו לעולם ולאחרים מותר למ"ש מיד **ובשוגג אסור בו ביום גם לאחרים ולערב מותר גם לו מיד** <sub>ואם אמר לעכו"ם לעשות מלאכה בשבת ע"ל סי' ש"ז סעיף כ</sub>
>
> One who cooks food on Shabbos <sub>[or performs any one of the other forbidden acts on Shabbos][Tur];</sub> if done intentionally, the food is forbidden to eat forever, but other people are permitted to eat the food immediately after Shabbos. **If done accidentally the food is forbidden to him during the day but may be eaten by everyone, including him, immediately after Shabbos**. <sub>[If one ordered a non-Jew to perform a Melacha for oneself on Shabbos, see above Siman 307 se’if 20].</sub>

If we follow the rules that Yom Kippur = Shabbos, perhaps one could suggest to extend this halacha found in Hilchos Shabbos to Hilchos Yom Kippur. Namely, that if one accidentally cooked food on Yom Kippur then perhaps said food may be eaten by everyone (including him!) immediately after Shabbos.

### Again, this is purely conjecture and SHOULD NOT be relied on in any way: please be sure to [CYLOR](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cylor)

Comment: Don't be so unsure your 100% correct that Yom Kippur is like shabbos the questioner clearly misheard something quoted in the name of Rabbi Zilberman